# Rails has_many_through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to set up a Rails application which has Records categorised by type and subtype; a type will have several subtypes and each subtype will have many records. Deleting a type or subtype should fail if there's anything associated with it. I'd have thought that this might work, but I find that trying such things as `record.type` or `type.records.count` doesn't return anything. Here's the setup:

```
class Type < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :subtypes, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
    has_many :records, through: :subtypes, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
end

class SubType < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :type
   has_many :records, dependent: :restrict_with_exception
end

class Record < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :subtype
   has_one :type, through: :subtype
end
```

And then, some migrations to add the relevant fields to the already-existing classes:

```
class LinkTypesSubtypesAndRecords < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
    def change
        add_reference :subtypes, :record, index: true
        add_reference :subtypes, :type, index: true
        add_reference :records, :subtype, index: true
        add_reference :types, :subtype, index: true
    end
end
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your migration you should add reference

1. of `subtype` in `records` table
2. of `type` in `subtypes` table

So the migration should look like this:

```
class LinkTypesSubtypesAndRecords < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
    def change
        add_reference :records, :subtype, index: true
        add_reference :subtypes, :type, index: true
    end
end
```

For more information [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference)

## **Update 1**

In your models:

```
class Record < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subtype

  delegate :type, :to => :subtype, :allow_nil => true
end
```

Comment: Thanks - that gets me the subtype from type or subtype from record, but if I have an instance of record I can't get its type directly, or from a type list al records, e.g. Type.first.records. Clearly I am misunderstanding something about how this should work.

Comment: Thanks again - the addition of the delegation did the trick. Also, I realised that I had a problem with a failing validation for some of my test data which was causing associations to not be created, and causing unnecessary confusion.

Comment: @knirirr glad it helped :)